# Google adsense doubleclick crawl errors

Tags: adsense

Google adsense crawl this page http://www.finewallpaperss.com/doubleclick that is not available on my site.

following is url that attempt many times by Google adsense.

http://www.finewallpaperss.com/doubleclick/DARTIframe.html?gtVersion=200_26&mediaserver=http%3A%2F%2Fs0.2mdn.net%2F879366&xpc=%7B%22cn%22%3A%22peerIframe1377068657642%22%2C%22tp%22%3Anull%2C%22osh%22%3Anull%2C%22pru%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.finewallpaperss.com%2Fdoubleclick%2FDARTIframe.html%3FgtVersion%3Drelay_200_26%26mediaserver%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fs0.2mdn.net%2F879366%22%2C%22ppu%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Frobots.txt%22%2C%22lpu%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.finewallpaperss.com%2Frobots.txt%22%7D

Any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the DoubleClick DARTIframe issue, you will need to create a new folder in the root directory of your website named as doubleclick. For example, the one we have here is http://techie-buzz.com/doubleclick/ and then upload a file provided by them called DARTIframe.html to that directory.
https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/156583